# How to create a user to for Jenkins to execute command as a root user?

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

When I create a Jenkins job with Git to manage the source code, I enter a local repository URL, it failed:

```
Failed to connect to repository: Command"git ls-remote -h /myRepositoryPath HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr:fatal: '/myRepositoryPath' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I try this command via terminal, it works, cause I have already init the directory and commit it. I guess **anonymous user** makes this error happens, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of url do you use?
If use use `git@...`, then login must perfomed via key
and you should place `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files to jenkin's `~/.ssh` directory.